# Apache Cordova: can't get commons-codec

Tags: android, cordova, apache-commons-codec

I am trying to create a new Android project with Apache Cordova. The script starts but fails with the message:

> Could not retrieve the commons-codec. 
>   Please download it yourself and put it in the framework\libs directory. 
>   This process may fail now.
>   sorry.

And then it fails. I have it running on Windows 8 64bit. ANT, ADT, Android-SDK, Eclipse, Java are all running fine. I run the cmd as admin, no difference. I downloaded the 1.7 version of commons-codec.jar and put it in the lib directory not only of Cordova but also of ant and Android SDK but that did not make any difference.

I hope someone can help me, and I want to thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Download the 1.6 version of commons-codec at [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6) and then copy it you the \framework\libs folder in your Cordova folder.

Worked great for me.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can it at Apache's historical archive of old software releases: http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/binaries/